# how to resolve kernel_security_check_failure

Tags: windows-8, kernel, nokia-pc-suite

I am trying to re-install my Nokia-E5 software by Nokia suite ,I have windows-8.1 OS on my laptop  , I am getting this error  `kernel_security_check_failure` . And my laptop restarts.
I have no idea how to fix this issue. 
Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is a BSOD (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj569891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). upload the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump** or the file **C:\Windows\Memory.dmp**